# Kivy MDDatePicker - TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callback'

Tags: python, datepicker, kivy, kivymd

https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/pickers/index.html#mddatepicker

This code is coming from the official presentation page so it may be a Github issue to raise ?

*The widget is under testing. Therefore, we would be grateful if you would let us know about the bugs found.*

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker

KV = '''
MDFloatLayout:

    MDToolbar:
        title: "MDDatePicker"
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 10

    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "Open time picker"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        on_release: app.show_date_picker()
'''


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_save(self, instance, value, date_range):
        '''
        Events called when the "OK" dialog box button is clicked.

        :type instance: <kivymd.uix.picker.MDDatePicker object>;

        :param value: selected date;
        :type value: <class 'datetime.date'>;

        :param date_range: list of 'datetime.date' objects in the selected range;
        :type date_range: <class 'list'>;
        '''

        print(instance, value, date_range)

    def on_cancel(self, instance, value):
        '''Events called when the "CANCEL" dialog box button is clicked.'''

    def show_date_picker(self):
        date_dialog = MDDatePicker()
        date_dialog.bind(on_save=self.on_save, on_cancel=self.on_cancel)
        date_dialog.open()


Test().run()
```

`TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callback'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MDDatePicker does not work with `kivymd-0.104.1`. You must install `kivymd-0.104.2.dev0` for it to function.

```
pip uninstall kivymd
pip install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you, PyCharm doesn't propose this version for the moment, I added it from the PyCharm terminal. It's working on local version, I'm gonna try to create an .apk.

Comment: Glad it helped! Just make sure to include the 0.104.2 version in your .spec file. Instead of writing kivymd, you have to just paste the link in there. Remember this! It caused me a *lot* of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing an argument `callback`

```py
date_dialog = MDDatePicker(callback=self.get_date)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).